# p:password doesn't redisplay prefilled model value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, passwords

i have my managed bean like this :

```
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped
public class utilisateur implements Serializable {

    private String login ="yous" ;
    private String password ="yous";
    ...
    ...

}
```

and my login.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="login: " />  
<p:inputText value="#{utilisateur.login}"  />  

<h:outputText value="password: " />  
<p:password  value="#{utilisateur.password}"  />
```

so with this configuration the password must be shown by default like `****` (yous) in `p:password` but it shows empty.

Comment: only the password is missing? or login field also is empty?

Comment: yes only the password was missing

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for security reasons. You need to explicitly set the `redisplay` attribute to `true` if you need to display the password from the model whenever it's been submitted or preset.

```
<p:password value="#{utilisateur.password}" redisplay="true" />
```

See also [the `<p:password>` VDL documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.0/core/primefaces-p/password.html), it's the one before last attribute.

> `redisplay` Boolean flag indicating whether or not a previously entered password should be rendered in form. **Default is false.**

Comment: @BalusC JSF next version should be named as BalusC. :-)